# Get HTML element via aria-label Excel VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, yahoo-finance

I'm trying to extract earning release dates from yahoo finance (e.g. https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?symbol=WIX). It seems like aria label is reliable, but not sure how to get that from the html.

[image: Please see the aria label and element to be extracted in below screenshot]

Comment: Do you have to use VBA, or can you use something friendlier, such as Python (which has [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/)) for html parsing?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with the results, but the table is easily accessible via Power Query -- available in Excel 2010+.

Comment: use a [css attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) via querySelector. Lots of examples for VBA on SO of this.